# C# How to Display Image(resource) array in TabPage

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Goal: when the application starts I want to generate a button per each picture in my resources (6 for testing, 128 final build), in side of a `TabPage`.

Here is where i am at so far:

```
private void tabPage1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSet("");
    IDictionaryEnumerator id = rs.GetEnumerator();
    List<Bitmap> CIcons = new List<Bitmap>();
    while (id.MoveNext())
    {
        if (id.Value is Bitmap)
            CIcons.Add((Bitmap)id.Value);
    }
}
```

this doesn't seem to do the trick, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Edit(addition): the issue is when the application starts I'm not seeing the images listed int "tabPage1".

also yes i do have 6 images added to my "Resource Folder" inside Visual Studios.

Just for future folks i wanted to add the finished working code:

```
        // Button list start
        // Credit to Jcl
        ResourceSet rs = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        IDictionaryEnumerator id = rs.GetEnumerator();
        List<Bitmap> CIcons = new List<Bitmap>();
        while (id.MoveNext())
        {
            if (id.Value is Bitmap)
                CIcons.Add((Bitmap)id.Value);
        }


        int yposition = 0;
        foreach (var bmp in CIcons)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(0, yposition);
            button.Size = new Size(125, 125);
            button.Visible = true;
            button.BackgroundImage = bmp;
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(button);
            yposition += 125; 

        }
        //Button list end
```

Comment: Did you add the images to `Resources.resx` file?

Comment: I do have the images in the resource folder,  my issue is im not seeing the end result on the form when it loads. what would be a good way to isolate weather the issue is being called from resource or being "rendered" on the form when loaded?

Comment: Don't you use a `.resx` file? Did you set your images as embedded resources? It's unclear what you are asking. Also it's unclear if you have problem with reading the images or problem with adding them as buttons to the `TabPage`.

Comment: Break your question to smaller parts and set your first goal to read images from resources. Then for your second goal (in fact your second question if you need) try to add images as buttons to `TabPage`. Describe all required information which may help to solve the problem and share errors that you have received when you run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a button, I'd say something like:

```
private void tabPage1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSet("");
    IDictionaryEnumerator id = rs.GetEnumerator();
    List<Bitmap> CIcons = new List<Bitmap>();
    while (id.MoveNext())
    {
        if (id.Value is Bitmap)
            CIcons.Add((Bitmap)id.Value);
    }

    // Vertical aligned: i'll let you figure out how to position them
    int yposition = 0;
    foreach(var bmp in CIcons)
    {
       var button = new Button();   
       button.Location = new Point(0, yposition);
       button.Size = new Size(50, 20); // for example
       button.Visible = true;
       button.BackgroundImage = bmp;
       tabPage1.Controls.Add(button);        
       yposition += 20; // height of button

    }
}
```

---

#### Update

As noted in the comments (I thought it was example code, but seems it's not), you also need to specify where to get the `ResourceSet` from. In your case, change:

```
ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSet("");
```

for

```
ResourceSet rs = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
                                  CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
```

---

## Code legibility bonus

All this code:

```
IDictionaryEnumerator id = rs.GetEnumerator();
List<Bitmap> CIcons = new List<Bitmap>();
while (id.MoveNext())
{
    if (id.Value is Bitmap)
        CIcons.Add((Bitmap)id.Value);
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
List<Bitmap> CIcons = new List<Bitmap>();
foreach(var bmp in rs.OfType<Bitmap>())
  CIcons.Add(bmp);
```

And since you can create a list from an enumerable, you could simply do:

```
List<Bitmap> CIcons = new List<Bitmap>(rs.OfType<Bitmap>());
```

But also, since you are not using your bitmap list for anything else than creating the buttons, you could just not define it, and then your whole code becomes:

```
var rs  = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
                         CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
int yposition = 0;
foreach (var bmp in rs.OfType<Bitmap>())
{
    var button = new Button()
    {
        Location = new Point(0, yposition),
        Size = new Size(125, 125),
        Visible = true,
        BackgroundImage = bmp,
    };
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(button);
    yposition += 125; 
}
```

This could be further optimized: if I was you, instead of positioning by calculating the pixel location of each component, I'd use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) to arrange the buttons. Usage of the `FlowLayoutPanel` is way outside the scope of this question though, I'm just mentioning it just in case you want to investigate and google further

Comment: i attempted this and i'm still not seeing buttons/images in the tabpage. maybe my event/call is all wrong?

Comment: Sorry, did it from head... change `this.Controls.Add(button)` to `tabPage1.Controls.Add(button)`. See update

Comment: Btw, I assumed this was example code, but you are not specifying a filename nor getting your `ResourceSet` from a `ResourceManager`... I was hoping the resources part was already right and your problem was adding the controls to the tabpage... but if you are creating your `ResourceSet` passing an empty string, there's no way there'll be any resource loaded from it. You need to either pass it a filename or get it from the generated `ResourceManager`

Comment: I got the same thing, i attempted to throw it in Public Form1() { the code}, and got a error at "ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSet("");"  saying: "empy path name is not legal"

Comment: Yes, that's what I was commenting: where are you putting your resources?

Comment: I see from the update: the resources folder is not enough to get resources compiled for winforms (or to get a `ResourceSet`)... you should be generating a resource file (`.resx`) which links those images in your resources folder. After that, you'll have a class generated with the name of the `resx` file plus the default namespace of your project... then you can do `ResourceSet rs = ResourceClassName.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);` with `ResourceClassName` being the generated class

Comment: i guess we posted right at the same time on that one xD. as far as my resource location Project_name/Resources/  (note im using visual studios, so i added them to the project via the gui).   also i thought by creating the resource set i was calling all files with a "name" in resources

Comment: i went back over my project and i do have a Resources.resx file. with fun and exciting code like:  internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap Akali {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("Akali", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }

Comment: The class name i mentioned should be on top of that file

Comment: Okay, im really a dummy... how do i do that?

Comment: @StromReedy I added the explanation, and some bonus "code-optimization" tips :-)